# How do I store images in a python script using Tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I want to render an image in tkinter but I always end up with an error saying that the image (PieTalk.gif) could not be found even though the image is in the same directory as the python script (startupgui.py):

```
 /Home/COMP3203/COMP30203-project/src/ptgui/
```

Here is the method where I want to render an image in a GUI. The following code is a class called startupgui.py. It consists of a constructor and a method to load the image

Constructor:

```
def __init__(self):

    # String to decide whether to go to client or server
    self.trigger = None

    #-----------------------#
    # Creating window frame #
    #-----------------------#
    self.root = Tk()
    self.root.wm_title("PieTalk")
    self.root.geometry('600x450')

    # creating PieTalk image
    self.createimage()
    # creating buttons
    self.createbuttons()
```

Method to load image:

```
def createimage(self):

    # Creating image frame
    self.imageframe = Frame(self.root, bg='light grey')
    self.imageframe.place(relx=0.1, relwidth=0.8, rely=0.05, relheight=0.65)

    # Creating PieTalk image
    self.pietalkimage=PhotoImage(file="PieTalk.gif")

    # Creating label
    self.imagelabel = Label(self.imageframe, image=pietalkimage)
    self.imagelabel.image = self.pietalkimage
    self.imagelabel.pack()
```

I have used the file name only:

```
self.pietalkimage=PhotoImage(file="PieTalk.gif")
```

And I have also used the absolute path to the file:

```
self.pietalkimage=PhotoImage(file="/Home/COMP3203/COMP30203-project/src/ptgui/PieTalk.gif")
```

Unfortunately, I keep on getting the same error when I execute the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pietalk.py", line 361, in <module>
    startview=sgui.startupgui()
  File "/home/archit/COMP3203/COMP3203-project/src/ptgui/startupgui.py", line 66, in __init__
self.createimage()
  File "/home/archit/COMP3203/COMP3203-project/src/ptgui/startupgui.py", line 33, in createimage
  self.pietalkimage=PhotoImage(file="/Home/COMP3203/COMP30203-project/src/ptgui/PieTalk.gif")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3387, in __init__
Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3343, in __init__
self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "/Home/COMP3203/COMP30203-project/src/ptgui/PieTalk.gif": no such file or directory
```

Is there something else that I am doing wrong when I am loading the image? What else can I do to load an image?

Answer (score 2):

first convert it to base64 python variable

```
>>> import base64
>>> with open("my_image.py","w") as f:
...    f.write('my_image="""%s"""'%base64.b64encode(open("my_gif.gif","rb").read()))
...
>>> exit()
```

you should now have the my_image.py file there ... copy that to the same directory as your tkinter script... an now you can do

```
from my_image import my_image
image=PhotoImage(data = my_image)
```

since you are having some problems lets try and simplify it a little bit

**img2base64.py**

```
import base64,sys,os,re
assert len(sys.argv) > 2,"Error: Useage %s /path/to/image.gif outfile.py"
assert os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]),"Error Unable to find image passed in as first argument"
outfile = open(sys.argv[2],"w")
raw_binary_data = open(sys.argv[1],"rb").read()
b64_encoded_data = base64.b64encode(raw_binary_data)

varname = re.sub("[^W]","_",os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.argv[1]))[0])
pyname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.argv[2]))[0]
outfile.write("%s='''%s'''"%(varname,b64_encoded_data))
outfile.close()

print "all done please put %s in your script directory and use it as follows:"%sys.argv[2]
print "from %s import %s"%(pyname,varname)
print "image=PhotoImage(data = %s)"%(varname)
```

just save that and then call it

```
$ python img2base64.py /path/to/image.gif pyimage.py
```

I think at least I didnt try it ...

Comment: Did you run the script in the terminal? When I ran that script in a linux terminal, it didn't reach:  >>> exit()

Comment: what do you mean it didnt reach that line? did it give an error? (I didnt actually run it... but its fairly straight forward

Comment: I ran the first script as pietalklogo.py in the same directory as the tkinter script. I also ran it without exit(). After I ran startupgui.py with the imports suggested above (replaced my_image with 'pietalklogo'), I got an ImportError: No module named 'pietalklogo'.

Comment: you are supposed to run the `>>>` stuff in the python terminal ... I just tested it and it works fine (the image needs to be in the same folder that you are running the python terminal from)

Comment: Once I ran in the python terminal, I had the same problem mentioned the first time. It doesn't reach >>> exit(), remaining stuck after     runningf.write('pietalklogo="""%s"""'%base64.b64encode(open("PieTalk.gif","rb").read())). I also run the python terminal from the same directory as the image.

Comment: what do you mean stuck? what happens when you hit enter?

Comment: After hitting enter, it displayed 17217.

Comment: After running startupgui.py with the imports suggested and running teh first script successfully, I get the following import error: "ImportError: No module named 'pietalklogo'."

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by previous answer:

```
import base64
from pathlib import Path
import sys

src = Path(sys.argv[1])
dst = src.with_suffix(".py")
with dst.open("w") as f:
    data = base64.b64encode(src.read_bytes()).decode('utf-8')
    f.write(f'image="{data}"')
exit()
```

and I tested it ;-)